# Book like view in iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad, cell

I am looking for a Book like view for a iOS native application. More like this

[image]

So you can see the verses follow one after the other rather than in a cell view. Also I would like to want to select a particular verse if required by tapping on the verse.

What view can I use other HTML Webview?

Comment: What makes this a book view? Please be specific of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

WebView is probably your easiest option, but you could also check out [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).

Comment: Just like a regular bible, I am looking to create a continuous view one verse after the other. The user would be able to touch on a particular verse and select it. http://churchdrop.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/holiwrit-1.jpeg